# How to deploy code from scratch org to real org

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

I am using the below commands to deploy my code from scratch org to developer edition instance (from where the scratch org has been created). There is no error coming but In the org , I can't find the component.

```
1.sfdx force:source:convert --outputdir mdapi_output_dir --packagename managed_pkg_name
2.sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d mdapi_output_dir/ -u "test-ao4atmzxhvkt@example.com" -l NoTestRun
3.sfdx force:mdapi:deploy:report
```

Comment: What does the report say?

Comment: @DavidReed, you're right. I used the correct user and the components are deployed correctly to the developer edition instance.

Answer (score 4):

This method is no longer necessary, and I wouldn't encourage using it. Simply deploy the source directly:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -w 10 -p force-app -u "test-ao4atmzxhvkt@example.com"
```

The output from this command should show you which components were deployed.

Comment: the report says all the component has been deployed successfully.
Job ID | 0Af6D00000JsZoNSAV
MDAPI PROGRESS | ████████████████████████████████████████ | 2/2 Components

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be deploying to the wrong org. "test-ao4atmzxhvkt@example.com" is a scratch org user, not a Developer Edition user. You can determine the relevant username or org alias for your Developer Edition by running `sfdx force:org:list`.